# Linkedlist Memory Read Error

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list, but I have a problem about memory access. I debug the code, see where it gives error, but cannot solve it. With using 'Add watch', can see the `next` has unable to read memory error.

```
struct Node
{
    string Name;
    Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList
{
    Node* head = NULL;
    bool isX = true;
};


LinkedList* initX(string Arr)
{
    LinkedList* link = new LinkedList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->Name = Arr[i];
        Node* ptr = new Node;
        ptr = link->head;
        if (link->head != NULL)
        {
            while (ptr->next)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
        else
            link->head = temp;
    }
    return link;
}
```

```
Unhandled exception at 0x008E8AF7 in ...exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDE9.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Note that `Node* ptr = new Node; ptr = link->head` leaks memory. First you allocate memory for `ptr` then overwrite what it points to by reassigning it. Though that isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: If `link->head == NULL` you still don't set `link->next` to `NULL` after you do `link->head = temp`.

Comment: This code will fail if that string you're passing to `initX` is < 15 characters.  How about posting the `main()` function?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thank you. What do you mean with "link->next to NULL" I did not use it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this string is constant, so it won't fail

Comment: @user4052080 Sorry, I meant you have to do `temp->next = NULL` after `link->head = temp` in the `else` part.

Comment: If my below answer doesn't help then we need a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

After you set `link->head` to `temp` in the `else` part of your `if` statement, you don't set `temp->next` to `NULL`, thus making any use of `temp->next` as if it had a value in undefined behavior. Add this to your `else` part:

```
else {
    link->head = temp;
    temp->next = NULL; // or nullptr
}
```

It would actually be better if you moved both `temp->next = NULL`, made them into one, and put it as the last statement in the `for` loop. That why you don't have to do the same thing for both conditions.